# How to use child class in android Java (inheritance)

Tags: java, android, class, inheritance, android-listview

I am fairly new to coding please help me understand how to use inheritance in android with Java. Let me explain my question with an example :

Like there is a parent class called "Animal" which includes "name" and "age" and has two subclasses "Dog" and "Cat". The "Dog" class has "name", "age", "food" and the "Cat" class has "name", "age", "breed" as their attributes.

From my understanding the best practice is to make:

1. Animal class with the attribute of "name", "age" + constructor and getter and setter

```java
public class Animal{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Animal() {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

2. Dog class extends of Animal class with an attribute of "food" and put getter and setter

```
   private String food;
   

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }
}
```

3. Cat class extends of Animal class with an attribute of "breed" and put getter and setter

```
    private String breed;


    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }
}
```

4. MainActivity should be like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Animal> mAnimal = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setName("The Dog");
        dog.setAge(2);
        dog.setFood("Bone");

        Cat cat = new Cat();
        cat.setName("The Cat");
        cat.setAge(1);
        cat.setBreed("Persian");

        mAnimal.add(dog);
        mAnimal.add(cat);

       
    }

}
```

Now Since there are three classes and each class has a different attribute, How to implement listview to show a list of all animals and their foods or breeds (depends on which one they have) in Mainactivity?

I would really appreciate your answers in advance

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with your questions. as your question currently stands, it's not very focused - you're asking various different questions and you haven't shown what you've tried so far

Comment: refer to the following link on how to create tables for inherited classes https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server

Comment: Thank you for your advice @a_local_nobody, I did revise the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question Refers to Inheritance but also to polymorphism.

create a super class and sub classes

```
class Animal {
  protected String name;
  protected int age;

 public void animalSound() {
    System.out.print("The animal makes a sound");
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {

  private boolean isLivesAtHome;

//getters & setters

//override function from super class
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.print("The Cat says meow");
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
private boolean isWasVaccinatedAgainstRabies;

//getters & setters

//override function from super class
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.print("The dog says bow wow");
  }
}
```

run this on Main function like this:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal myAnimal = new Animal();  // Create a Animal object - Super Class
    Animal myCat = new Cat();  // Create a Cat object
    Animal myDog = new Dog();  // Create a Dog object

        ArrayList<Animal> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(myCat);
        arr.add(myDog);
        arr.add(myAnimal);

        //simple for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){

            //if the object is a Cat instance
            if(arr.get(i) instanceof Cat){

                //change Cat instance variable
                ((Cat)arr.get(i)).setLivesAtHome(true);

                System.out.println("I'm a Cat");
            }

            //print animalSound function
            arr.get(i).animalSound();
        }
  }
}
```

This code print's:

```
I'm a Cat
The Cat says meow
The dog says bow wow
The animal makes a sound
```

This example show Polymorphism and inheritance concept using single `ArrayList`.

The list is of animals. Of the Super Class type.

A `dog` is also an `animal`, a `cat` is also an `animal` (by inheritance) so you can add them to the `Animal` List.

If you want to refer a particular object (like the Cat in the example code), you have to use 'instance of' operator for Casting.

for more info you can read about `Inheritance` and `Polymorphism`.

Comment: Thank you @h.mozrahi, That was a very helpful explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this or similar to this.

Models:

Animal:

```
public class Animal {

Dog dog;
Cat cat;

public Animal(Dog dog, Cat cat) {
    this.dog = dog;
    this.cat = cat;
}

public Animal() {
}

public Dog getDog() {
    return dog;
}

public void setDog(Dog dog) {
    this.dog = dog;
}

public Cat getCat() {
    return cat;
}

public void setCat(Cat cat) {
    this.cat = cat;
}
```

Dog:

```
public class Dog {
String name;
String age;
String food;

public Dog(String name, String age, String food) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.food = food;
}

public String getFood() {
    return food;
}

public void setFood(String food) {
    this.food = food;
}
```

Cat:

```
public class Cat {
String name;
String age;
String breed;

public Cat(String name, String age, String breed) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.breed = breed;
}

public String getBreed() {
    return breed;
}

public void setBreed(String breed) {
    this.breed = breed;
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    Animal animal = new Animal();
    animal.setDog(new Dog("tomi", "6","Roti"));

    List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
    animals.add(animal);

    Log.d("Jay", animals.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are askings reffers to polymorphism. It means subclass inherits everything from it's superclass.

To achieve what you want you would create your objects like:

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
((Dog) dog).setBreed("Terrier"); //This is called Casting
...
Animal cat = new Cat();
...
```

And then in your ListView when showing data you can check if your object is instance of particular object, like this:

```
if(dog instanceof Dog)
   textView.setText(((Dog) dog).getBreed());
```